Laravel 11 - validated() and related table
I'd like to insert the user-id of the current user into a table in column "user_id". The field is a relation to the user table.
Migration / database schema
        Schema::create('pdlocations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->decimal('lon', 10, 7);
            $table->decimal('lat', 10, 7);
            $table->string('map'); 
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); 
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');
        });

In the controler (PdlocationController.php)
   public function store(PdlocationStoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->merge([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
//            'user_id' => auth()->user(),
        ]);
     
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        ]);

        Pdlocation::create($request->validated());
           
        return redirect()->route('admin.pdlocation.index')
                         ->with('success', 'Pdlocation created successfully.');
    }

If merging into the request the current userID auth()->user()->id I get the following error message:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

insert into
  `pdlocations` (`map`, `lon`, `lat`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
values
  (test, 66, 55, 2024 -06 -21 18: 42: 57, 2024 -06 -21 18: 42: 57)

If merging into the request instead the user object auth()->user() the validator says The selected user id is invalid.
Any idea or suggestion what I'm missing?

I think the main problem here is that user_id doesn't exist in the $fillable attribute inside the model.
Apart from this, what you are trying to do here isn't really the best, you shouldn't validate the user_id anyways, what you need to do is make sure this route is guarded by the auth middleware, and therefore Auth::id() will always contain the valid id of the currently logged in user, and should be merged after the validation
// make sure this route has the auth middleware
public function store(PdlocationStoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        // all the fields including user_id should be in the model's $fillable attribute
        Pdlocation::create([...$request->validated(), 'user_id' => Auth::id()]);
           
        return redirect()->route('admin.pdlocation.index')
                         ->with('success', 'Pdlocation created successfully.');
    }


Unfortunately your solution is not working for me, see my comment above.
By the way, rules and validateion is better managed in the StoreRequest in a method ´prepareForValidation()´

Man! you've been right, user_id was missing in $fillable :)

There is a proper way in Laravel to add custom attributes while using Request class.
For an example below is an array of the rules
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'map'=>'required',
        'lon'=>'required',
        'lat'=>'required',
        'user_id' => 'nullable' // It will overwritten by the below method
    ];
}

protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()?->id
    ]);
}

So now you've user_id each time you uses the PdlocationStoreRequest.
In the controller Simply do like
Pdlocation::create($request->validated());
return redirect()->route('admin.pdlocation.index')->with('success', 'Pdlocation created successfully.');

It will help you to get rid from writing repetitive codes.

I already had a prepareForValidation() method in my Store Request, does not work.
Now I had a look after the validated values and got an array with the user_id within. But even it's in the validated data, the user_id is not in the SQL insert query. Any idea?

Got it!  If forgot to add the "user_id" in my model $fillable!
Thanks for your help. learned a lot!

just use request methods like
$request->validated()

to get some of the inputs you can use
$request->safe()->only('name')

